# Connecting to a database on a different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sqlconnection

I have a WPF application where the user enters database information in some textboxes. Once the user clicks "connect", a connection string is created from what the user had entered and a connection is established. I noticed that if the user enters any info that is wrong, the application will hang until the connection times out. By hang, I mean the user can't interact with the rest of the application at all.

**It is my goal to keep the application responsive while the connection string is tested.**

I thought that putting this workflow on a different thread is a good solution. My idea is to just disable anything that may need a database connection while the thread runs. Once the thread comes back (and has has confirmed the connection string to be valid) I would re-enable everything. Otherwise, leave everything disabled.

However, the `Thread` class doesn't have an event notification when the thread is done (or at least I am unaware of one).

I have also worked with the `BackgroundWorker` class. This works better. However, when the `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler` event is fired and the connection string isn't valid, I get the following exception:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

This is probably because the connection still hasn't timed out when the completed event handler is fired.

Does anybody have any ideas, or should I just NOT try to multithread a connection to a database?

A code outline of what I am doing:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    dbTool = new DBTool();
    // Create the connection string
    e.Result = dbTool.connectToDB(); // connectToDB() returns a bool (true if connection established)
}

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // connectToDB() returns a bool (true if connection established)
    if(e.Result == true)  // Trying to read e.Result here throws the exception
    {
        // e.Error and e.Cancel should be checked first
        // However, I would like the thread to finish before
        // this event is fired
    }
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?  You've mentioned both. Also, how close to this example is the real code? Neither `Console.WriteLine()` nor `e.Error` should be able to throw this exception.  Updating a UI control might, though.

Comment: @SeanU: I have updated my question. There is little missing from my actual code.

Comment: You should swap the order in which you're checking those properties.  Accessing `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`'s `Result` property will raise an exception if its `Error` property is not null.

Comment: From MSDN:

If the operation completes successfully and its result is assigned in the DoWork event handler, you can access the result through the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property.

and:

Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler should always check the Error and Cancelled properties before accessing the Result property. If an exception was raised or if the operation was canceled, accessing the Result property raises an exception.

Comment: @SeanU: I understand that, but that is the problem. I need the thread to finish before I check the `Result` property. i.e., before `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` is fired.

Comment: A `BackgroundWorkder` won't raise `RunWorkerCompleted` until it completes, is canceled, or raises an exception.  You should be able to verify this by placing a breakpoint in your `RunWorkerCompleted` handler and then looking at the Parallel Stacks window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input.

I was able to come up with a solution. After coming across [Working With The WPF Dispatcher](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher). I determined that you can obtain the UI thread's `Dispatcher` object:

```
//...

dbTool = new DBTool();
// Initialize the connection string
// Disable some UI
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
        delegate()
        {
            dbTool.connectToDB();
            UIControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
              new Action(
                  update
            ));
        }
));
thread.Start();

//.....

void update()
{
    if (dbTool.validString)     // If the connection string was valid
    {
        // Re-enable controls
    }
    else     // Invalid connection string
    {
        // Keep controls disabled if no connection could be created
    }
}
```

This indeed will test the connection string on a different thread, leaving the rest of the application responsive.

Answer (score 3):

Don't preserve your `DbConnection` object in a single global variable and share it between threads.

The .NET environment will automatically pool your connections and share them, so calling `new DbConnection()` is very fast.

You should keep the connection string in a global variable, but then create connections as required on each thread.

EDIT: The original poster may have actually wanted ideas on how to keep the WinForms application responsive while a connection string is being tested.  In that case, you want to spawn a different thread to test the connection.  From the "connection test thread," you can update the UI by following this pattern - [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

```
public void TestConnectionThread(String connstr_to_test)
{
    // Notify the user that we're doing our test
    string message = "Testing...";
    lblTestResultMessage.SetPropertyThreadSafe(() => lblTestResultMessage.Text, message);

    try {
        dbTool = new DBTool();
        message = dbTool.connectToDB();

    // If something failed, show a useful debugging message
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        message = ex.ToString();
    }

    // Use a lambda expression to communicate results to the user safely
    lblTestResultMessage.SetPropertyThreadSafe(() => lblTestResultMessage.Text, message);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I am not preserving the DBConnection object. I am merely just testing the connection string that is built from the data that the user enters. The object is deleted after that (I am using connection pooling).

Comment: Oh, I think I understand.  Does this mean you're trying to test the connection string while keeping the WinForms application responsive while the connection string waits to timeout?

Comment: @cshemby: That is exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

From [DBConnection's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**

In other words, different threads should never share a database connection, because the instance cannot safely be shared.  As Ted Spence suggests, you should instead create connections only as you need them (and `.Dispose()` them when you're done with them).  .NET has a built in connection pooling mechanism that does a very good job of making sure connections are reused when possible, but holding onto connections any longer than is absolutely necessary can interfere with its ability to do that.

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, but I am *not* sharing a connection. I just want one thread to test the connection string while application is able to stay open.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dbtool tool = e.result as dbtool;
```

If you have a variable in dbTool that that gets set to true or false when the query completes then you should be able to call

```
tool.variable = true/false
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as I said in the question trying to access e.Result in `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` throws an exception.

Comment: what does your connectToDB look like?

Comment: Boilerplate connection pooling.